# How to detect a UITextView contains clickable text (date, link, time, address etc)

Tags: events, hyperlink, uitextview

I have

1. a UITextView on top of
2. a background image, same size

Goal:

1. If UITextView contains any clickable text (link, date, time, address etc), tap event should work property (open link, create appointment, show map etc)
2. If UITextView does not contain any of that, background image should respond to the tap event (e.g.: show action sheet)

Challenge:

1. I can set userInteractionEnabled to NO, but how to detect UITextView contains link or not? I don't want to write my own code to do this check
2. Is it possible to make it that when UITextView contains a link, but tapping rest of it (plaint text) will trigger background image's tap event handler?

Thanks!